# Flex : Clone function duplicate my data

Tags: apache-flex, clone

I've some strange behavior using ObjectUtil.copy() and ByteArray.writeObject/readObject().
I clone an ArrayCollection and sometime the result is two identical instance of the class.

Example :

```
var item:Object = new Object();
item.name = "Hello World";

var listItem:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
listItem.push(item:Object );

var cloneList:ArrayCollection = ObjectUtil.copy(listItem);

trace(cloneList.length);    
// 2
```

I don't understand what I've done wrong. Is there something is missed ?
It is not reproductible for all ArrayCollection. Some time, it works fine.
Is it a bug of ObjectUtil.copy() function ?

Comment: Copy does not mean clone. Make your own clone method where you create new objects and copy properties values.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a clone of an array collection that will hold references to the original array collection's instances, can you not just clone the source array ?

e.g.

```
var listItem:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
listItem.push(item:Object );

var cloneList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(new Array().concat(listItem.source));
```